# A quasi-isometric embedding of a convex cocompact subgroup

Tags: rt.representation-theory, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, geometric-group-theory

I am currently reading a paper where they state the following claim:

"For a convex cocompact representation $\rho: \Gamma \to G$, the existence of a cocompact invariant convex set $\mathcal{C}$ implies (by the Svarc-Milnor lemma) that $\rho$ is a quasi-isometric embedding."

The context here is that $G$ is a real semisimple Lie group of real rank one, and $X = G/K$ is its corresponding symmetric space (here, $K$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $G$). A convex cocompact representation as above is given by a subgroup $\Gamma < G$ together with a convex subset $\mathcal{C}$ of $X$ which $\Gamma$ preserves, and acts with compact quotient.

Reviewing some literature, it seems to be known that $X$ has negative sectional curvature, and hence we can say (by Svarc-Milnor) that $\Gamma$ is word hyperbolic. However, I fail to see how the inclusion $\Gamma \hookrightarrow G$ is a quasi-isometric embedding. One of the papers that I have consulted points to *Marc Bourdon, Structure conforme au bord et flot géodésique d’un CAT(−1)-espace, Enseign.
Math. (2) 41 (1995), no. 1-2, 63–102. MR 1341941 (96f:58120)*  for a proof of this fact, but I cannot seem to find this article online.

I also tried to see that maybe the inclusion was a Q.I. embedding just by definition, but this approach was not fruitful for me.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: $C$ is convex so is [large-scale] geodesic, so by cocompactness $\Gamma\to C$, $g\mapsto gx_0$ is a quasi-isometry (for any fixed $x_0\in C$, which has to assumed nonempty). Also the inclusion $C\to X$ is isometric. So $\Gamma\to X$ is a QI-embedding.

Comment: @YCor that was so simple, thank you!